# How can I make jquery validation work with my jedatible plugin?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, jeditable, unobtrusive-validation

I’m trying to implement jquery validation with my jeditable plugin.. As jeditable is somewhat new to me I thought I’d add try using code I found on the forum. Here’s my original code that works fine except for validation.

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"      type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.jeditable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {

     $(".display-label").editable("/Course/RubricsEdit");

     $(".text").editable("/Course/RubricsEdit",
                    {
                        submitdata: {
                            DepartmentId: function () {
                                return $("#DepartmentId").val();
                            },
                            RecordType: "DEPARTMENT"
                        }
                    });
```

Then I tried this:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {

       $(".display-label").editable("/Course/RubricsEdit");

       $(".text").editable("/Course/RubricsEdit",
                    {
                        submitdata: {
                            DepartmentId: function () {
                                return $("#DepartmentId").val();
                            },
                            RecordType: "DEPARTMENT"
                        }
                    });

   $(".text").editable("/Course/RubricsEdit", {
   submitdata: function (settings, td) {
    var input = $(td).find('input');
    $(this).validate({
        rules: {
            'nameofinput': {
                number: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            'actionItemEntity.name': {
                number: 'Only numbers are allowed'

            }

        }
    })

    return ($(this).valid());
     }
 });


 });
</script>
```

Still works but no validation happens.. is there a way to make validation work with my jeditable plugin?

UPDATE:
So I tried this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {





     $(this).validate({
         rules: {
             submitdata: {
                 number: true
             }
         },
         messages: {
             submitdata: {
                 number: 'Only numbers are allowed'
             }

         }
     });





     $(".display-label").editable("/Course/RubricsEdit");

     $(".text").editable("/Course/RubricsEdit",
                    {
                        submitdata: {
                            DepartmentId: function () {
                                return $("#DepartmentId").val();
                            },
                            RecordType: "DEPARTMENT"
                        }
                    });



 });
</script>
```

…and got an error message:

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'validate'.  What could I be missing?

Comment: Regarding your last edit.  You have to attach `.validate()` to **your form**.  `$(this)` means absolutely nothing where you've used it.  `$('#myformid').validate()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to write your own validation rules manually (by calling `$(this).validate({...}`) you can no longer use unobtrusive validation. So get rid of the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js` script as it is of no use to you anymore. The whole point of unobtrusive validation is that ASP.NET MVC helpers will inspect your model properties and if they are decorated with validation attributes (such as `Required`) emit the corresponding HTML5 `data-*` attributes on the input elements that will be used by the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js` script to dynamically register the validation rules within `jQuery.validate`. If you use the plugin separately with your own rules, you should not use unobtrusive validation as both don't work together.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your code:

```
$(".text").editable("/Course/RubricsEdit", {
   submitdata: function (settings, td) {
    var input = $(td).find('input');
    $(this).validate({ // <-- this is in the wrong place
        rules: {
            'nameofinput': {
                number: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            'actionItemEntity.name': {
                number: 'Only numbers are allowed'

            }

        }
    })

    return ($(this).valid());
     }
 });
```

Part of your problem is that you are trying to manually apply jQuery Validation to each `input` using `.validate()`.

[`.validate()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) is only supposed to be used *once* within DOM ready to **initialize** the plugin on the *form*, **not** for validating each field manually.  The plugin takes care of all field validations automatically.

[`.valid()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) can then be used, *after* `.validate()` is initialized, to force a validation test on the form and/or return the corresponding boolean value of the result (for the whole form).

I also noticed that the name of your input `'nameofinput'`, does not match the corresponding `'actionItemEntity.name'` within `messages: {}`.  These must be the same if that's the corresponding message you're trying to over-ride.  ([You only need quotes around the input `name` if it contains special characters like periods and brackets.](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Fields_with_complex_names_.28brackets.2C_dots.29))

Something like this to get you back on track:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#yourform').validate({
        rules: {
            nameofinput: {
                number: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            nameofinput: {
                number: 'Only numbers are allowed'
            }

        }
    });

});
```

**Simple Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/Hr3bB/

Comment: I tried your suggestion but got an error:  Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'validate'. What could I be missing?

Comment: @CloudyKooper, I now see why you're getting an error.  Regarding your last edit:  You have to attach `.validate()` to **your form**.  `$(this)` means absolutely nothing where you've used it.  See the code inside my jsfiddle.  `$('#myformid').validate()`.  (_It's partly my fault for blinding moving your code without fixing that in my OP._)

Comment: I see where your code would work attaching the validation to the form.  The thing is jeditable creates its own form dynamically and when I wrap my jeditable fields in a form that I create myself, the fields are no longer editable.